# Creating a new Android Project in Terminal-IDE

Tags: android, terminal-ide

Is there a script or something that creates a new Android project in Terminal IDE on Android? How does the R file get updated with new resources?

Answer (score 0):

This might help : http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html

It will create a project that can be used...with ant.

Maven has an archetype system that can create a new Android project : https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes

There doesn't seem to be any gradle equivalent (yet).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your project's home folder and then create the

```
./src
./dist
./res
./build
./build/classes
```

directories and add an "AndroidManifest.xml" file manually.
It works. Copy the "builder.sh" script in the project's home folder and make the proper changes like `cd` into your project's home folder, set your project's package name and select the main activity class.
As per your question about the R.java file, the `aapt` tool from Android SDK detects the changes in resources and writes R.java file and packs resources accordingly.